# selecting data by column then by null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following data in it

```
User_Id CpyId   SortOrder ColName
NULL    NULL    1         User_Id
NULL    NULL    2         User_Code
NULL    NULL    3         User_Name
NULL    NULL    4         User_Type_Descr
100001  NULL    1         User_Id
100001  NULL    2         User_Name
100001  NULL    3         User_Type_Descr
100001  NULL    4         User_Code
NULL    1       1         User_Id
NULL    1       2         User_Other_Name
NULL    1       3         User_Type_Descr
NULL    1       4         User_Code
```

I want to preferentially choose the CpyId if that matches the CpyId input if not match on UserId else using the NULL rows

Is there a better way of doing it then this

```
declare @UserId int, @CpyID int

select @UserId = 100002, @CpyId =1;

With Company_Filter As 
(select * from tbl_Entity_Column_Details where Company_Id = @CpyId),
 User_Filter As 
(select * from tbl_Entity_Column_Details where User_Id = @UserId)

select * from Company_Filter
union
select * from User_Filter where not exists (select * from Company_Filter)
union
select * from tbl_Entity_Column_Details where User_Id is null and Company_ID is null 
and not exists (select * from Company_Filter)
and not exists (select * from User_Filter)
```

Comment: Not getting what you want. You said you have 1 table, but your query show 3

Comment: the table is called tbl_Entity_Columns_Details the two others are cte's

Comment: And your not exists checks aren't going to do what you want. The second query will return ALL rows from User_Filter IF Company_Filter has no rows.

Comment: No it only returns rows where the User Id is equal to what is passed in

Comment: That is because of your where predicate. The EXISTS piece will not return rows if there are any rows in Company_Filter. Essentially where User_Id what is passed in AND there are no rows in Company_Filter

Comment: So the query works, you just want to find out the better way to do this?

Comment: yeah I want to only see the CpyId matches if available else see if there are matches on user if not use the default (null user and cpy)

Comment: just want to see if there is a more elegant way of doing it

Comment: I think it is not very readable according to reaction of pps here, but if it works it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean "CpyId" and not "CompanyId" in your where clause.
So the way I would do it is get all possible results and rank them.
Then just select the result with the minimum rank.

```
--Declare UserId and CpyId
declare @UserId int = 100001
declare @CpyID int = 1;

--Select all possible results and rank
WITH subryUnion 
AS (

--Select hits by CpyId, Rank 1
SELECT *, 
    1 AS Ranking,
    'Hit by CpyId' Descr
FROM tbl_Entity_Column_Details
WHERE CpyId = @CpyId

UNION ALL

--Select hits by User_Id, Rank 2
SELECT *, 
    2 AS Ranking,
    'Hit by User_Id' Descr
FROM tbl_Entity_Column_Details
WHERE User_Id = @UserId

UNION ALL

--Select no hits by CpyID or User_Id, Rank 3
SELECT *,
    3 AS Ranking,
    'Not hit by CpyId or User_Id' Descr
FROM tbl_Entity_Column_Details
WHERE COALESCE(CpyId,User_Id) IS NULL

)

SELECT *
FROM subryUnion
--Show only the minimum ranked results
WHERE Ranking = (SELECT MIN(Ranking) FROM subryUnion)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first COALESCE() will look by the ID first... if not, go to USER.  if User is still not found, then it by default is NULL for the final ID.

The SECOND column does case/when so you can similarly identify WHICH mode it was found (or NULL) if not.

The (@variables) sqlvars will create a single row result so it is the basis of the JOIN, then by doing left join on respective IDs, will always return 1 row for a minimum to LEFT-JOIN the other table in each join capacity.

```
SELECT
      COALESCE( byID.CpyID, byUser.User_ID ) as WhichID,
      CASE when byID.CpyID IS NOT NULL then "ID"
           when byUser.User_ID IS NOT NULL then "USER"
           ELSE null end as WhichID, "NULL"      
   from 
      ( select @UserId = 100002, @CpyId =1 ) sqlvars,
         LEFT JOIN tbl_Entity_Column_Details byID
            ON @CpyID = byID.CpyID

         LEFT JOIN tbl_Entity_Column_Details byUser
            ON @UserID = byUser.User_ID
```